# how to create select field in cart rule form admin magento 2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart

can you please suggest me how to create custom field set in shopping cart rule for magento 2 admin. Actually i want to set shopping cart rule for perticular customer with perticular product. can you please suggest how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create customer group for particular customer and set product to that customer.

[image]

After created customer group you can assign any catalog rule to that customer group.

Comment: Sorry i think you didn't understand the question. i want set the rule for particular customer not customer group vise. I know how to create rule and all.

Comment: you can set that customer group to particular customer that's not big issue